# $\varphi:M\to A^n$; $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)$ finitely generated

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ring-homomorphism

I read the following question:

> Let $M$ be a f.g. $A$-module and $\varphi:M\to A^n$ a surjective $A$-homomorphism. Show that $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)$ is finitely generated.

I was thinking about this, because seems to be obvious that $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi)$ is finitely generated, once is a submodule of $M$ (f.g.).

Maybe I do not understand the question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well if $A$ is not assumed noetherian, it might happen that submodule of finitely generated module aren't finitely generated (this is pretty much the definition of being noetherian). So you should prove that this can't happen here.

Comment: Interesting...!  Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the title, it even is false for $K$-vector spaces ($K$ being the base field). Consider $n$ distinct scalars $a_1, a_2,\dots, a_n$, and the linear map:
\begin{align}
f:K[X]&\longrightarrow K^n \\
P&\longmapsto\bigl(P(a_1),P(a_2),\dots,P(a_n)\bigr)
\end{align}
This map is surjective because of the existence of the Lagrange polynomial.

As stated in the question itself (with $M$ finitely generated) it is true if $A$ is a *coherent ring*:

Indeed, $M$ is the quotient of a finitely generated  free module, i.e. there exists some $m\in\mathbf N$ and a surjective map $\;p:A^m\longrightarrow M$.

Now, as $A^m$ and $A^n$ are coherent modules, $\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi\circ p)=p^{-1}(\operatorname{Ker}\varphi)$ is coherent, which implies it is finitely generated, hence $\operatorname{Ker}\varphi=p\bigl(\operatorname{Ker}(\varphi\circ p\bigr)\bigr)$ is finitely generated.

Comment: Hi, many thanks! But in this case $Ker(\varphi)=\langle (x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)\rangle$ and is finitely generated?

Comment: As an ideal in  $K[X]$, not as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Sorry, I know you are correct, but once $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots(x-a_n)\in K[X]$ I cannot see how is not f.g. Sorry my stupidity...

Comment: Just commenting to note that Na'omi is right and this doesn't work. If you consider these as $K[X]$-modules, the kernel is finitely generated and, if you consider them as $K$-modules, then $K[X]$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: The kernel is the ideal of all multiples  of $(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\dotsm(X-a_n)$ and as  any principal ideal, it is isomorphic to $K[X]$ as a $K[X]$-module, and also as a $K$-vector space.

Comment: Right, the claim is that if $M$ is a finitely generated  $A$-module and $\phi: M \to A^n$ is surjective, then the kernel of $\phi$ is finitely generated. So your counterexample needs to have $M$ finitely generated but $\mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$ not so.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't notice the `f.g` for $M$.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the surjectivity.

Comment: Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 5):

This problem is true as stated, with no hypotheses on the ring $A$, because of the hypothesis that $\phi : M \to A^n$ is surjective. Let $K = \mathrm{Ker}(\phi)$, so we have a short exact sequence $0 \to K \to M \to A^n \to 0$.

The short version of what I want to say next is "$A^n$ is free, so $0 \to K \to M \to A^n \to 0$ splits, so $M \cong K \oplus A^n$." Here is the longer version. Write $\iota$ for the inclusion $K \to M$ and $\pi$ for the surjection $M \to A^n$. Let $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_n$ be the generators of $A^n$. Lift them to $m_1$, $m_2$, ..., $m_n \in M$, meaning that $\pi(m_j) = e_j$. Let $\sigma : A^n \to M$ be the map $\sum a_j e_j \to \sum a_j m_j$. So $\pi(\sigma(x)) = x$. This map $\sigma$ is called a splitting (or sometimes, a right splitting) of the sequence $0 \to K \to M \to A^n \to 0$.

Whenever you have a splitting, you can do the following trick: For $m \in M$, let $\rho(m) = m - \sigma(\pi(m))$. Since $\pi(\rho(m)) = \pi(m) = \pi(\sigma(\pi(m))) = \pi(m) - \pi(m) = 0$, we have $\rho(M) \in K$. So $\rho$ gives a map $M \to K$. As an exercise, check that $\rho(\iota(k))=k$ for any $k \in K$ and $\rho(\sigma(x)) = 0$ for any $x \in A^n$.  I claim that $M \cong K \oplus A^n$. The map in one direction is $m \mapsto (\rho(m), \pi(m))$; the inverse map is $(k, x) \mapsto \iota(x)+\sigma(x)$. Checking that these are inverse is left as an exercise.

So, the short way or the long way, we conclude that $M \cong K \oplus A^n$. In particular, $K$ is a quotient of $M$, and $M$ is finitely generated, so $K$ is as well.

See Wikipedia's article on [split short exact sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_exact_sequence) for more.

---

Under many conditions, the hypothesis that $\phi$ is surjective is not needed. For Noetherian rings, any submodule of a finitely generated module is finitely generated, so you are done immediately. More generally, if $R$ is a [coherent ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_ring), the kernel of any map $A^m \to A^n$ is a finitely generated $A$-module.

The simplest example I know of a non-coherent ring is $A=k[x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots]/\langle x_i x_j \rangle_{i \leq j}$. In other words, take the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables and set all products of two variables equal to $0$. Then multiplication by $x_1$ is a map $A \to A$, whose kernel is the maximal ideal $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, \rangle$, but this maximal ideal is not finitely generated.

Comment: Hi, many thanks! But in this case, is not surjective, is it? For instance, $x_2\not\in Im(\varphi)$

Comment: Oh, good point. I'll fix that.

Comment: It turns out that surjectivity makes the statement true! See edit.

Comment: Hi. I am studying a little more your answer and 'd like to ask you for more details at "this gives a splitting of the surjection $M \to A^n$. So $M \cong K \oplus A^n$". I am beginner and realized that could not understand very well. Thank you.

Comment: See if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! (1) I'll bounty you as a little award for extra help. (2) As a little detail, I believe that "Let $\sigma : A^n \to M$ be the map $\sum a_j e_j \to \sum a_j e_j$." should be "Let $\sigma : A^n \to M$ be the map $\sum a_j e_j \to \sum a_j m_j$.", but not sure. Many thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! And that is indeed a typo; I'll fix it.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr. Speyer.